# checkbox group decorator using zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, decorator

I wnat to display checkbox group using zend form multicheckbox but not getting the use of decorators. i am bringing the array list from the database in an key value pair array..

```
<td><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                            <tbody><tr>
                              <td width="25" align="center" height="22">                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox27" name="group[]">            </td>
                              <td>Pharmaceutical</td>
                              <td width="25" align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox34" name="group[]"></td>
                              <td>Biotechnology</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" height="22"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox28" name="group[]"></td>
                              <td>Environmental/Agro  Chemical</td>
                              <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox35" name="group[]"></td>
                              <td>Medical  Device</td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody></table></td>
```

how can i set this using decorators..

Comment: Please work on your Accept-Rate and try to write words like "Thanks" in your questions. Otherwise no one is going to answer your questions.!!!!!

Comment: Pushpendra: dude how can i make answer as correct if no one gives correct answer. I have not got any answer to this question so i have solved it myself. very frequently i ask silly questions.. and i always appreciate people who help me and also try to help.. i think you better understand this..

Comment: Jaimin: happy to hear that you solved it by yourself, but don't you think if you put that answer in this thread it will be helpful for the other persons in similar need. And here you can accept your answer also and that will also increase your accept-rate.....

Comment: Pushpendra: First of all sorry for being bit rude. i will post it definitely but right now stuck in project. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662735/doctrine-2-0-cascase-error this is my asked question previously and i posted my answer as well when i got it right..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible with ZF decorators. If it is, it will be an overkill solution. So maybe you could just play a bit with css?! Cause I don't see any other difficulties but the styling. Or am I missing something?

A normal multicheckbox is listed as labels. You can float these labels to the left and give them a width that equals the width of your placeholder divided by 2. And so on for other styling.

Comment: Tim: i have found out the solution to this. i had to made a custom decorator and also custom helper to solve this issue.